# How to join transactional data with customer data tables and perform case-based operations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, querying

I'm trying to perform a query between two different tables and come up with a case by case scenario, coming up with a list of records of calls for a specific month.

Here are my tables:

**Customer table:**

```
+----+----------------+------------+
| id |      name      |   number   |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | John Doe       | 8973221232 |
|  2 | American Dad   | 7165531212 |
|  3 | Michael Clean  | 8884731234 |
|  4 | Samuel Gatsby  | 9197543321 |
|  5 | Mike Chat      | 8794029819 |
+----+----------------+------------+
```

**Transaction data:**

```
+----------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| trans_id |  incoming  |  outgoing  | duration |      date_time      |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | 8973221232 | 9197543321 |       64 | 2018-03-09 01:08:09 |
|        2 | 3729920490 | 7651113929 |      276 | 2018-07-20 05:53:10 |
|        3 | 8884731234 | 8973221232 |      382 | 2018-05-02 13:12:13 |
|        4 | 8973221232 | 9234759208 |      127 | 2018-07-07 15:32:30 |
|        5 | 7165531212 | 9197543321 |      852 | 2018-08-02 07:40:23 |
|        6 | 8884731234 | 9833823023 |      774 | 2018-07-03 14:27:52 |
|        7 | 8273820928 | 2374987349 |      120 | 2018-07-06 05:27:44 |
|        8 | 8973221232 | 9197543321 |       79 | 2018-07-30 12:51:55 |
|        9 | 7165531212 | 7651113929 |      392 | 2018-05-22 02:27:38 |
|       10 | 5423541524 | 7165531212 |      100 | 2018-07-21 22:12:20 |
|       11 | 9197543321 | 2983479820 |      377 | 2018-07-20 17:46:36 |
|       12 | 8973221232 | 7651113929 |      234 | 2018-07-09 03:32:53 |
|       13 | 7165531212 | 2309483932 |       88 | 2018-07-16 16:22:21 |
|       14 | 8973221232 | 8884731234 |       90 | 2018-09-03 13:10:00 |
|       15 | 3820838290 | 2093482348 |      238 | 2018-04-12 21:59:01 |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

**What am I trying to accomplish?**

I'm trying to compile a list of "costs" for each of the customers that made calls on July 2018. The costs are based on:

1) If the customer received a call (incoming), the cost of the call is equal to the duration;

2) if the customer made a call (outgoing), the cost of the call is 100 if the call is 30 or less in duration. If it exceeds 30 duration, then the cost is 100 plus 5 * duration of the exceeded period.

If the customer didn't make any calls during that month he shouldn't be on the list.

**Examples:**

1) Customer American Dad has 3 incoming calls and 1 outgoing call, however only trans_id 10 and 13 are for the month of July. He should be paying a total of 538:

- for trans_id 10 = 450 (100 for the first 30s + 5 * 70 for the remaining)
- for trans_id 13 = 88

2) Customer Samuel Gatsby has 1 incoming call and 3 outgoing calls, however only trans_id 8 and 11 are for the month of July. He should be paying a total of 722:

- for trans_id 8 = 345 (100 for the first 30s + 5 * 49 for the remaining)
- for trans_id 11 = 377

Considering only these two examples, the output would be:

```
+----+----------------+------------+------------+
| id |      name      |   number   |  billable  |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+
|  2 | American Dad   | 7165531212 |        538 |
|  4 | Samuel Gatsby  | 9197543321 |        722 |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Note: Mike Chat shouldn't be on the list as he didn't make or receive any calls for that specific month.

**What have I tried so far?**

I've been playing cat and mouse with this one, I'm using the number as uniqueID, already attempted both a full outer join and combining where incoming or outgoing is not null then applying rules by case, tried doing a left join and applying cases, but I'm circling around and I can't get to a final list. Whenever I get incoming or outgoing, I'm either not able to apply the case or not able to come with both together. Really appreciate the help!

```
select customer_name.name, customer_name.number, bill = (CASE
                                                         WHEN customer_name.number = transaction_data.incoming then 'sum bill'
                                                         else 'multiply and add'
                                                         end)
from customer_name
left join transaction_data on customer_name.number = transaction_data.incoming or customer_name.name = transaction_data.outgoing
where strftime('%Y-%m', transaction_data.date_time) = '2018-07'
```

Note: I'm using sqlite to try it out online but the database is on SQL Server 2012, so I know that I can use a date format much easier, that way, but I'd like to keep as close to T-SQL as possible.

Also tried creating a case to determine whether it's incoming call or outgoing, but I'm only getting incoming as a result, even though trans_id 10 is outgoing:

```
select name, number, duration, case 
    when customer_name.number = transaction_data.incoming then 'incoming'
    when customer_name.number = transaction_data.outgoing then 'outgoing'
END direction
from customer_name
left join transaction_data on customer_name.number = transaction_data.incoming or customer_name.name = transaction_data.outgoing
where strftime('%Y-%m', transaction_data.date_time) = '2018-07'
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I'm still buinding the DB and I'm fine with either MySQL or SQL Server solution, but for the sake of tagging I've changed it to SQL Server, also added some code that I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  c."name", c.number,
  SUM(CASE c.number
        WHEN t.incoming THEN t.duration
        ELSE IIF(t.duration - 30 < 0, 0, t.duration - 30) * 5 + 100
      END) AS billable
FROM Customer AS c INNER JOIN [Transaction] AS t
  ON c.number IN(t.incoming, t.outgoing)
WHERE t.date_time >= '20180701' AND t.date_time < '20180801'
GROUP BY c."name", c.number
```

**Output:**

```
|     name      |   number   | billable |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| John Doe      | 8973221232 |      440 |
| American Dad  | 7165531212 |      538 |
| Michael Clean | 8884731234 |      774 |
| Samuel Gatsby | 9197543321 |      722 |
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4039b/1).

Comment: Awesome, didn't think about adding a case inside the sum, it became much more simple than I thought! Thanks!